# Navbar Collapse with Brand wont let me center the links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to make a bootstrap navbar with a logo on the left-hand side that will collapse when the window is shrunken. I want to have my links between pages be in the center of the navbar, however when I set the text to text-align: center in my css, the links are off to the right by a factor which I can only assume is the width of my brand. To try to fix I have tried setting both the text position to absolute, as well as the position of the brand on separate attempts. Although both of these will make the links be in the middle of the page on full screen, when I make the page smaller the collapse functionality no longer works. Any solutions to where I can have the links be in the actual center of the screen while maintaining my ability to collapse the navbar?

```css
#navcollapse{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#navbar-brand{
    height: 60px;
}

#nav{
    text-align: center;
 }

#logoimg{
    height : 60px;
    
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #311149; 
}

.navbar-custom { 
    background-color: #e9ecef ; 
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg" id = "nav" >
        <a class="navbar-brand" id = "navbar-brand">
            <img src = "https://www.fifplay.com/img/public/premier-league-logo.png" id = "logoimg">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcollapse" >
            &#9776;                     
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div> 

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-link "><h4>Table</h4></a>
            <a href="{% url 'fixtures' %}" class="nav-link"><h4>Fixtures</h4></a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link"><h4>Clubs</h4></a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link"><h4>Players</h4></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

[image]

To do it, just comment all the code inside `#navcollapse`:

```
#navcollapse {
     /* position: absolute; */
     /* left: 50%; */
     /* transform: translateX(-50%); */
  }
```

EDIT: Based on your last comment, if you want that, it could be implemented by adding `media` tag for specific screen:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
       #navcollapse {
           position: absolute;
           top: 80%;
           left: 50%;
           transform: translateX(-50%);
       }
   }
```

You can edit the `top: 80%` to the % that you want.

Comment: Yes that is what I want it to look like when it collapses. The problem is when it is in full-screen the links arent in the center of the page if I remove that css like u said the links are slightly off to the right of center by a length of what I assume is the size of my logo

Comment: So if I include this css that u highlighted it puts it in the right position when it is in fullscreen, but the collapse no longer works

Comment: I edited the answer. Check it again to see if it matches with what you mentioned.